# Several occurrences of same Anchor Tag string

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

I have several occurrences of same Anchor Tag string in one document - /sn1/. But when signing I can see only one generated field - near the first match. Documentation says that a sign tab is created in every place a match is found in a document. What am I doing wrong or should strings be unique?

Update: I have the document in Hebrew(RTL) language, probably it's somehow connected with the problem, as I tested another document, but this time in English, and had multiple fields at the place of anchor string instances with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was incorrect convertation via libreconv gem that prevented additional sign tabs from appearing. The problem was in initial convertation from .docx to .pdf using the above mentioned gem. I do not recommend it at least for RTL documents.